# Filemaker ejecutar script en el servidor

Tags: servidor

Buenas,

Estoy intentando mejorar la velocidad de mi base de datos y he visto que la función "ejecutar guión en el servidor" puede ser la solución. La base de datos va bien desde WebDirect pero si te conectas a través de Filemaker Pro va muy lento en algunas presentaciones.

La cuestión es que he hecho una función muy simple para probar que funciona pero nada...

Guión "prueba":

> ejecutar guión en el servidor["prueba PSoS"]

Guión "prueba PSoS":

> establecer variable[Global::prueba ; Global::prueba & "Esta ejecutando prueba PSoS"]
>   ir a la presentación["prueba"]

Guión "OnFirstWindowOpen":

> If[LeftWords (Get (ApplicationVersion) ; 1) = "Server")]
>   `establecer variable[Global::prueba ; Global::prueba & "Esta ejecutando prueba OnFirstWindowOpen"]`
>   `salir del guion[];`
>   end If

En el campo "prueba" de la tabla "Global" el resultado es = "Esta ejecutando prueba OnFirstWindowOpen Esta ejecutando prueba PSoS".

El problema es que no ejecuta la función "ir a la presentación["prueba"]" y se queda en la misma presentación

Tengo mi archivo de filemaker alojado en FMPhost.com en un servidor en la nube filemaker 14.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo cómo hacer la prueba de tu script pero me parece que la OnFirstWindowOpen está dentro de las comillaspor lo que FMP lo entiende como cadena de texto. Prueba colocando la orden fuera de las comillas.